# How to make a pow of 2 numbers in 8 bits in assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, pow, emu8086, 8-bit

My problem is: I want to make a pow of 2 numbers in 8 bits and save the result in 16 bits, I can't use operations in 16 bits in the process, like "MUL BX" only 8 bits numbers and I should get results until 65535, I don't know how to do it without use MUL BX

```
org 100h 

mov cl, exp        ;9 
mov al, base       ;3

dec cl             

start:            
 mov bl,base
 mul bx            ;I can't use this
 loop inicio

mov result,ax      ;I should sabe result in 16 bits

int 20h

base db 3
exp db 9
result dw 0h
```

Comment: The 8 bit `MUL BL` produces a 16 bit result. Are you allowed to use that?

Comment: Do you have any other arbitrary restrictions?  Or any performance requirement?  If not, you can of course implement multiply with a shift-and-add loop.

Comment: yhea, I try to use ´MUL BL´ but I don't get results greater than 255, and I should save 65535 in result variable